# Why it's giving a 0.5 second time for rotating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
private void RotateTargetsRandom()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer > rotationTime)
        { // timer resets at 2, allowing .5 s to do the rotating
            qTo = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0.0f, Random.Range(-180.0f, 180.0f), 0.0f));
            timer = 0.0f;
        }

        foreach (var target in targets)
        {
            target.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(target.transform.rotation, qTo, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
    }
```

The function make that each 2 seconds the targets(GameObjects) will rotate.
But in the comment not my comment it say "timer resets at 2, allowing .5 s to do the rotating"

Where is the 0.5 part in the code ?

So each 2 seconds there is a rotation and the rotation is taking 0.5 seconds. I just don't understand where is the 0.5 part ? And if I want it to rotate duration of 0.1 time instead 0.5 ?

Comment: What are the (invisible here) variables `Time.deltaTime` and `speed`. What is the variable `rotationTime`? did you debug this and watched the variables?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Time.deltatime is not an invisible variable its incredibly common in unity

Comment: Thanks @BugFinder . I was actually wondering about their values. Isn't rotationTime, relevant here? How often this method is invoked I wonder also. Each frame? Maybe the OP is kind enough to provide some more information.

Comment: There are a number of unanswered details but sadly time.deltatime is not one of them

Answer (score 0):

What makes it rotate following a speed is the

```
target.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(target.transform.rotation, qTo, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```

Slerp is the spherical interpolation and it is basically interpolating between the current rotation of the object and the **qTo** value using the **deltaTime** (elapsed time since last frame in seconds) and an arbitrary **speed**.

e.g.
imagine you are only rotating in one axis to simplification, say the z-axis.
if the rotation is 0 and qTo is 45 in the first iteration it will be:

```
45 * deltaTime * speed
```

But since it is already set it to the transform rotation the next iteration will use the new rotation as the initial value of the interpolation:

```
(45 - previousRotation) * deltaTime * speed + previousRotation
```

Thus it is converging to 45 when `speed * sum(all deltaTimes)` is one.

So I suppose your speed is 2 since it is taking 0.5s to reach the target rotation.

But the code is a little flaky since it would behave weirdly if rotationTime is lower than 1 / speed.

It is not specified in the question but I believe you are calling it inside an Update(ish) method, to allow deltaTime to have a reasonable meaning.

So to control the duration of your rotation you set the speed to a desired value, to have a 0.1s duration set the speed to 10.